Cannot initialize a thread within a class method
I'm trying to create a thread within a class method that runs another method within the class, but it refuses to compile.
Here is a reproducible example:
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void foo() {std::cout << "Thread Running.\n";}

    void bar() {
        std::thread t(foo);
        t.join();
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.bar();
    return 0;
}

I get the following compiler errors:
In file included from E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/thread:45,
                 from C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Personal\Documents\Coding Projects\C++\Take Ship\src\test.cpp:1:
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h: In instantiation of 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A::*)(unsigned int); _Args = {}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]':
C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Personal\Documents\Coding Projects\C++\Take Ship\src\test.cpp:8:26:   required from here
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h:157:72: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  157 |                                       typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                                                        ^~~~~
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h:157:72: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A::*)(unsigned int)> >':
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h:236:13:   required from 'struct std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A::*)(unsigned int)> > >'
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h:164:29:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A::*)(unsigned int); _Args = {}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]'
C:\Users\trist\OneDrive\Personal\Documents\Coding Projects\C++\Take Ship\src\test.cpp:8:26:   required from here
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h:291:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A::*)(unsigned int)> >::__result<std::tuple<void (A::*)(unsigned int)> >'
  291 |           _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
E:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/std_thread.h:295:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A::*)(unsigned int)> >::__result<std::tuple<void (A::*)(unsigned int)> >'
  295 |         operator()()
      |         ^~~~~~~~

Build finished with error(s).

The most relevant message appears to be `error: static assertion failed:

std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues`

If I simply define the functions without the class, it compiles fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Use a lambda expression to capture your this pointer e.g. std::thread t{[this]{ foo(1); }}; (also note you have to provide your int argument)

@PepijnKramer No need for a lambda. It will also work with std::thread t(&A::foo, this);

@Yksisarvinen
Works perfectly, thank you!
Note: (The unsigned id param was a mistake so I've removed it from the code example)

@CatMek Make sure to read the duplicate question to understand what was wrong in the first place and how to pass member functions around.

Probably a side effect of the simple example, but just in case it isn't, don't join the thread immediately after starting it. The thread-starting thread will stop at the join to wait for the new thread to complete for a grand sum of 1 thread running at a time.

std::jthread t(&A::foo, this); https://godbolt.org/z/MGo7Pcnda please remember that all none-static member functions have hidden argument this.

Since C++23 this will be less cumbersome: Explicit object member functions.
